# How to select data from two table with out using "NOT IN" in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
Emp1
ID | Name
1  | X
2  | Y
3  | Z

Emp2
ID | Salary
1  | 10
2  | 20
```

I want to show the `ID`s from Emp1 which are not present in Emp2 with out using `NOT IN`

so the result should be like this

```
ID
3
```

now what i have done is this :

```
select  e1.ID
from Emp1 e1 left join  Emp2 e2
on e1.ID <> e2.ID
```

but i am getting this :

```
ID
1
2
3
3
```

so what should i do ?? WITH OUT using `NOT IN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `left join` with `is null` condition as below

```
select e1.id 
from emp1 e1
left join emp2 e2 on e2.id = e1.id
where e2.id is null
```

or `not exists` condition as below

```
select e1.id 
from emp1 e1
where not exists
(
  select 1
  from emp2 e2
  where e2.id = e1.id
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
select id from emp1
except
select id from emp2;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/db2f7/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    e1.ID
FROM Emp1 e1 LEFT JOIN Emp2 e2 on e1.ID = e2.ID 
WHERE e2.ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I like left joins for sake of performance, group joins would be better only if there where more fields to be compared and excepted

Answer (score 1):

What you need is what [parado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18270466/1579182) already said. Here's a good picture for some other Joins and what Range they give back:

[image]

Sarajog